# Simulate Json responses

Tags: java, javascript, spring-mvc, extjs

We are using in our project ExtJS with Spring MVC and most of the times the UI is developed before the backend which means that we need to go to the controller, create dummy methods in order to simulate Json responses for the Grids, etc.

Is there any framework you would recommend to simulate Json responses instead of always going to Java and creating a new method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Can't you just put prepared JSON **files** as static content on server and point to them instead of dynamic handlers?